# MVC 3 Autofac registrations and resolving

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, autofac

I'm busy with learning more about DI and using Autofac in MVC3.

In global.ashx I register all my types.

In a static HtmlHelper extension for example, how would you do the resolving of an instance? How and where do you keep the container to resolve an instance? Can I just put the IContainer I get at the application initialization from `builder.Build()` in a static variable?

Answer (score 3):

There is an autofac nuget package. Check out more details in Using Autofac in ASP.NET MVC 3 Apps at:

[autofac - my choice of ioc container](http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/archive/2011/09/22/autofac-my-choice-of-ioc-container.aspx)

I would not do DI through a helper here, I would inject what I can into the controller otherwise you're contributing to the service locator anti-pattern. You can inject at the root, as this is an 'ok' usage of the service locator pattern.